# Need a page without chrome for a SP365 App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am creating an AngularJS SPA on SharePoint 365. When I create the app (I've used NAPA and VS2013), the SP header bar and page icon and app title appear on the Default.aspx page and my app starts below that.

I need the page to be clean for my app -- no SharePoint "Chrome"

I can't find any resources to help me get rid of the default stuff. I tried to use a little jQuery to empty() the body but I lose my "" placeholder.

How can I get rid of the default Chrome and have a clean page to build on?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I was under the impression that by default the "app page" would always be clean in a SharePoint hosted app (at least mine always are), could you perhaps pastebin/gist your script references? (there are scripts to make the page brand based on host web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to remove the top bar:

```
div#suiteBar {
        display: none;
    }
```

and this one to remove logo SP and app Name:

```
#s4-titlerow{
    display:none!important;
}
```

Comment: I should have thought about a CSS solution ... one thing though, there is still a light gray bar at the top of the page with "Browse" and the Focus icon on the page ... Can that be hidden as well?

Comment: Never mind - #s4-ribbonrow{ display:none !important; } works for that ... THANKS!!!